# React Antd Element Type Invalid... got: Object... Error after upgrade

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, antd

I was previously on antd 3.7.0 and everything was working fine. I upgraded to the latest v3.23.4 and now I am getting this strange error:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>
> Check the render method of `Row`.

I understand this is a problem with it not getting the component correctly, but when I print the component Row I am getting a function:

[image]

This happens on all antd components. And again. The only thing that has changed is that I upgraded antd version. Why does it think the component is an object when it comes back as a function? Here is a quick snippet of how the page looks:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Row } from 'antd'

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    ...stuff

    render = () => {
        console.log(Row)
        return (
            <Row>
                ...More Content
            </Row>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Try recreating the problem with your `package.json` versions in a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-antd-styled-template-n8n96

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused because of the react-dom version.

Initial versions in `package.json`:

```
"react": "16.6.3",
"react-dom": "16.0.0",
"antd": 3.23.4",
```

I went and looked at what version react-dom is in react@v16.6.3:

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.6.3/packages/react-dom/package.json

They use react-dom@v16.6.1. So I upgraded react-dom to that version and everything is working smooth again.

New Versions in `package.json`:

```
"react": "16.6.3",
"react-dom": "16.6.1",
"antd": 3.23.4",
```

Comment: react-dom version is the key here